# Dev Express RibbonControl Image Size

Tags: c#, winforms, image, devexpress, ribbon

Is there any way to change the size of the image in a ribbon control. It is autosizing my images smaller than I would prefer, is this changeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably being done to match up with the [Microsoft Office UI Licensing Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx).  DevExpress, I believe, made their Ribbon controls compliant with the Microsoft UI standards, which put specific restrictions on sizing of many items inside of a Ribbon.

I doubt this can be changed, as it would (technically) be a violation of the Microsoft Licensing for Ribbons.